# Python: Create a multidimensional array from a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, ironpython

Please can you help, I am struggling how to create a multidimensional array from a loop.
I am looping through rows in a data table and want to pass these to an array.
Thanks
Jay

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataValueCursor
from System import  DateTime, TimeSpan, DayOfWeek
from datetime import date
import time


#define ID
idcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[str](table.Columns["ID"])

#define actual date
actualcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[str](table.Columns["ActualDate"])

#define duration
durationcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[int](table.Columns["Duration"])

#define Start, # of Months and # of days
startcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[int](table.Columns["Start Months"])
monthcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[int](table.Columns["Number of Months"])
daycursor=DataValueCursor.Create[int](table.Columns["Number Of Days"])

#define Min and Max Dates
mincursor=DataValueCursor.Create[str](table.Columns["Min Date"])
maxcursor=DataValueCursor.Create[str](table.Columns["Max Date"])

myPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
idxSet =    myPanel.FilteringSchemeReference.FilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()

bar = []
for row in table.GetRows(idxSet,idcursor,durationcursor,actualcursor,startcursor,monthcursor,daycursor):
#I would like this line to populate the array 
 bar.append(idcursor.CurrentValue)
```

Comment: what are you getting in `bar`?

Comment: Thanks I only get the idcursor values i.e. ['1', '2', '3']. I would like to see the other cursor values that are in the loop i.e durationcursor,actualcursor,startcursor,monthcursor,daycursor

Comment: you presumably only add the `idcursor` value because that's all you append to `bar`.  Have you tried appending the values of the other things in list form, like `bar.append([idcursor,durationcursor,actualcursor])` and so on?

Comment: yeah Danno, I get a error if I add say another cursor in like so     bar.append(idcursor.CurrentValue,durationcursor.CurrentValue)       This is the error Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: append() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Hi     for row in table.GetRows(idxSet,idcursor,durationcursor,actualcursor,startcursor,monthcursor,daycursor):
    brandList.append(idcursor.CurrentValue)
     durationList.append(durationcursor.CurrentValue)
     actualList.append(actualcursor.CurrentValue)
     startList.append(startcursor.CurrentValue)
     monthList.append(startcursor.CurrentValue)
     dayList.append(daycursor.CurrentValue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dannno had your answer in the comments.

You can do this with:

```
bar.append([idcursor.CurrentValue, durationcursor.CurrentValue, ...])
```

note the use of `[]`. This is different from

```
bar.append(idcursor.CurrentValue, durationcursor.CurrentValue, ...)
```

as using `[]` creates an array that contains all the values and appends that array to `bar`; whereas without `[]` will attempt to pass each value as a separate parameter to `bar.append()`, which doesn't work as you discovered.

You also mentioned that you tried:

```
bar.append(idcursor.CurrentValue)
bar.append(durationcursor.CurrentValue)
...
```

This will give you a one dimensional array that contains all your values. Since you said you wanted a multi-dimensional array, this won't work for you.